# Can YQL be used in Firefox Add-on Builder?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, yql, firefox-addon-sdk

Can [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) be used in Firefox Add-on Builder when I want to have an add-on that get elements by their ID from page source?

Comment: To get elements by their ID you would usually use `document.getElementById()`, why would one use YQL (which is Yahoo Query Language if I understand correctly) for that?

Comment: Thanks Wlad, but the issue is that this command will only enable me to search for an element within my own code but not in the source code of other pages. To make it clear, I need method that will allow me to search for an element in any given webpage (i.e., in its source code) and not only within the code I written. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Then you are mixing two questions here. "Is it possible to use YQL from an add-on created with the Add-on SDK?" Answer is "yes, easily" (see answer by erikvold below). Second and totally unrelated question: "Can YQL be used to search elements by their ID?" Answer is "unlikely" - but I wouldn't know, I can only answer add-on questions.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use YQL you simply need to use the "request" module `require("request")` for more information see https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/request.html

Comment: Hi Erik, Thanks for that-very interesting, still one issue is unsolved. After I used this module (which is for my understanding built in in the add-on builder) would it be possible to do manipulations on the text retrieved by the module with JQ? Any assistance on that is appreciated.